# Passing command lines to function to evaluate in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, eval

I have a function which is very open-ended that I use in several different applications. Instead of changing it everytime, I would like to pass several command lines as input for the function to evaluate using something like the eval function.

Thus, for example, my argument would be:

```
str={'a=32; 
  b=a+3*a^2+pi;
  c=sin(a)+cos(b)^2;'}
```

then I could call the function with str as an argument:

```
x=func(str)
```

these lines would be evaluated inside the function

how?

Thanks alot!

Comment: I realize that eval is to be generally avoided and hated by many, but wouldn't using eval work?

Comment: In most cases, such problems can be solved passing function handles, for example `bfun=@(a)(a+3*a^2+pi)`, inside the function you call `b=bfun(a)`

Answer (score 1):

I think @Daniel is right that function handles are the way forward. Based on your example, this is how you'd do it:

```
function x = testfun( a, bfun, cfun )
   b = bfun(a);
   c = cfun(a, b);

   x = a + b + c;
end
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
x = testfun( 32, @(a)(a+3*a^2+pi), @(a,b)(sin(a)+cos(b)^2) );
```